# Django Select across three models with filter criteria

Tags: django, django-models

I have three models:

```
class Vehicle(models.Model):
    Vehicle_ID = models.AutoField('ID', primary_key= True)
    Vehicle_VIN = models.CharField('FIN', max_length=30)
    Vehicle_DELETED = models.BooleanField('Gelöscht',default=False)

class Recall(models.Model):
    Recall_ID = models.AutoField('ID', primary_key= True)
    Recall_CODE = models.CharField('Rückruf-Code',max_length=500, unique= True)

class Vehicle_Recall(models.Model):
    Vehicle_Recall_ID = models.AutoField('ID', primary_key=True)
    Vehicle = models.ForeignKey(Vehicle, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Recall  = models.ForeignKey(Recall, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I want to make a Select Statement like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Vehicle INNER JOIN(Recall INNER JOIN Vehicle_Recall ON Recall.ID = Vehicle_Recall.Recall) ON Vehicle.ID = Vehicle_Recall.Vehicle WHERE Recall.ID=1 AND Vehicle.DELETED)=FALSE;
```

Is there a way to make such query in django?

Comment: You can use a [ManyToManyField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/) to relate `Vehicle` and `Recall`. It would simplify your queries a little

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You canuse the Django's ORM as follows (it is an example):

```py
    vehicles = Vehicle.objects.filter(Vehicle_DELETED=False).filter(
        Q(vehicle_recall__Recall__Recall_ID=1)
    )
```

which generates the following SQL query:

`SQL SELECT "vehicle"."Vehicle_ID", "vehicle"."Vehicle_VIN", "vehicle"."Vehicle_DELETED" FROM "vehicle" INNER JOIN "vehicle_recall" ON ("vehicle"."Vehicle_ID" = "vehicle_recall"."Vehicle_id") WHERE ("vehicle"."Vehicle_DELETED" = False AND "vehicle_recall"."Recall_id" = 1)`

2. You can use the raw query as follows:

```py
    vehicles = Vehicle.objects.raw(f"""
    SELECT * FROM Vehicle 
    INNER JOIN(Recall INNER JOIN Vehicle_Recall ON Recall.ID = Vehicle_Recall.Recall) 
        ON Vehicle.ID = Vehicle_Recall.Vehicle 
    WHERE Recall.ID=1 AND Vehicle.DELETED=FALSE;
    """)
```

and remember to adjust name of tables.

I propose the first solution, but the appropriate code depends on needs. I prepared only some example to present its simplicity.